# How to fetch data from database into a wso2 bpel process?

Tags: wso2, bpel, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-business-process

I want to fetch data from MySQL database into a WSO2 BPEL process (designed in wso2 developer studio eclipse). 
How to invoke the database from the bpel process?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a data service in DSS to fetch data from DB. Refer [1]. Then invoke that service from BPS using a bpel invoke like explained in [2].

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS321/RDBMS+Sample

[2] - http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2011/04/using-carbon-studio-model-wsbpel-process-using-bpel-editor/#scenario